# Slideshow of web pages (python)

Tags: python, pyqt4, urllib, sys

I'm trying to make a simple slideshow in Python to view 0.html, 1.html and 2.html with 3 seconds delay between them.

The script below shows 0.html in 3 seconds, then I get a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error. Any ideas?

**My code so far:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
import urllib


class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, url, dur):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        view = QWebView(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(view)

        html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()       
        view.setHtml(html)
        QTimer.singleShot(dur * 1000, self.close)


def playWidget(url, dur):
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = Window(url, dur)
        window.showFullScreen()
        app.exec_()

x = 0
while (x < 3):
    page = "%s.html" % x
    playWidget(page , 3)
    x = x + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create more than one `QApplication`, which is why your example dumps core. But in any case, it's a rather poor design if your program needs to create a whole new browser window to display each page. What you should do is load each new page into the same browser.

Here's a re-write of your script that does that:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
import urllib


class Window(QWidget):   
    def __init__(self, urls, dur):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.urls = urls
        self.duration = dur * 1000
        self.view = QWebView(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.nextUrl()

    def nextUrl(self):
        if self.urls:
            url = self.urls.pop(0)
            html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
            self.view.setHtml(html)
            QTimer.singleShot(self.duration, self.nextUrl)
        else:
            self.close()

def playWidget(urls, dur):
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window(urls, dur)
    window.showFullScreen()
    app.exec_()

urls = [
    'https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc20',
    'https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc768',
    'https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc791',
    ]

playWidget(urls, 3)
```